# Ways to design heavy data-centric web application in Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight-3.0

I have to build a web application in Silverlight. This application is entirely data centric with SQLServer 2008 as the database. 
What are different ways of handling this design problem? Someone told me RIAServices would be a great option, but I am not completely knowledgable of it.
One simple option I know of is creating WCFService and exposing the methods to perform the actions on the database object. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question :).

3rd option ADO.NET dataservice. But RIAService is the #1 right now for n-tier LOB applications.